# AdMob AD view controller closes immediately after opening

Tags: ios, swift, admob, viewcontroller

I made a sample app and I'm currently trying to test admobs with a login before it. Here's my code:

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511")
        return true
    }



}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if(Auth.auth().currentUser != nil)
        {
            self.presentLoggedInScreen()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func createAccountTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
            if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text{
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { user, error in
                    if let firebaseError = error {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: firebaseError.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .`default`, handler: { _ in
                        }))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        return
                    }
                    self.presentLoggedInScreen()
                })
            }

    }
    
    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text{
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { user, error in
                if let firebaseError = error {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: firebaseError.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .`default`, handler: { _ in
                    }))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return
                }
                self.presentLoggedInScreen()
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    func presentLoggedInScreen()
    {
        let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loggedInVC:LoggedInVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoggedInVC") as! LoggedInVC
        self.present(loggedInVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    

}
```

LoggedInVC.swift

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import GoogleMobileAds

class LoggedInVC: UIViewController, GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var showAdButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var logLabel: UILabel!
    var rewardBasedAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        logLabel.text = ""
        showAdButton.isEnabled = false
        
        rewardBasedAd = GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()
        rewardBasedAd.delegate = self
        rewardBasedAd.load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313")
    }
    
    @IBAction func logoutTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        do{
           try Auth.auth().signOut()
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } catch{
            print("Problem logging out!");
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        showAdButton.isEnabled = false
        if rewardBasedAd.isReady {
            rewardBasedAd.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    }
    
    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidOpen(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        logLabel.text?.append("An ad opened. \n")
    }
    
    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        logLabel.text?.append("An ad closed. \n")
    }
    
    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        logLabel.text?.append("An ad has loaded. \n")
        showAdButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    
    func rewardBasedVideoAdDidStartPlaying(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        logLabel.text?.append("An ad started playing. \n")
    }
    
    func rewardBasedVideoAdWillLeaveApplication(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd) {
        logLabel.text?.append("An ad caused focus to leave. \n")
    }
    
    func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
        logLabel.text?.append("An ad has failed to load. \n")
        print(error)
    }
    
    func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {
        print("Ad finished.")
    }
}
```

I'll post a video of what's happening, but basically the ad audio plays, it just doesn't keep the actual ad on screen nor append the updates to the label.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlUjPA_AwZQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: rewardBasedAd.load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "..." doesn't look right to me.

Comment: I took it straight off a tutorial on YouTube. The video I have below shows that the ad does load, but someone closes the controller right away.

Comment: Don't understand why someone would vote the question down, just looking for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use This Code....that code is working....

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    //showAdButton.isEnabled = false
    if rewardBasedAd.isReady {
        self.dismiss(animated: false) { () -> Void in
            rewardBasedAd.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
}
```

Comment: Reference to property 'rewardBasedAd' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit